# Migration from mq version 6 to 7.5 java client fails for jdk-linked compiled application

Tags: java, jvm, ibm-mq

My compiled code application with linked-in jdk fails on the first mq API call in 7.5 yet works using the 6.x API, regardless of classpath configuration.  Very similar sample code from the mqm distribution works in my same environment.

Corporate environment, I'm stuck (for now) in not moving to anything newer than 7.5; I'm aware that mq/7.5 is on extended support since April/2018 (no longer regularly supported).

I have a c++ compiled application (solaris x86) which links against the 1.7.0 jdk and invokes JNI_CreateJavaVM() to create a java runtime (some code is in c++, some is in java).  This code has worked for a long time with mq version 6.  It fails in the very first call to 'new MQTopicConnectionFactory()' with a FFST report to stderr.

Solaris/11, jdk/1.7.0, mq/7.5.0.9.  I've tried both 32 and 64 bit, as well as jdk/1.8.0.  I get the following error in the FFST report:

com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.CSIException: JMSCS0002

It is a java.lang.NullPointerException when trying to invoke reflection on some method internally.  It seems like a classloader problem, in that the jdk can't find the class by the reflection call.

However, when I run the SimpleWMQJMSPubSub.java program in the /opt/mqm/samp/jms/samples/simple directory in the exact same environment, that program works correctly.  That sample code is also calling 'new MQTopicConnectionFactory()' as the first (interesting) mq-related call as well.

Searches for the JMSCS0002 error seem to indicate it's a classpath issue or an environmental issue where the jars have been copied/moved/renamed.  This is a freshly installed 7.5.0.9 distribution on my machine with no changes.  Additionally, I feel like since the sample program works in this environment, the environment difference must be in the jvm-linked binary.

I've tried setting the classpath environment for my jvm to be only /opt/mqm/java/lib/com.ibm.mqjms.jar (which works perfectly fine with the sample mqm code), and I've tried setting the classpath to point to every single jar explicitly in /opt/mqm/java/lib, and I've tried setting it to just the directory itself /opt/mqm/java/lib/*; all of those attempts result in the identical failure in my code, and all of those attempts succeed in the sample code.

Running truss on my program and the sample code confirm that the same jars are being opened by the underlying jvm, with a small distinction: the java invoked sample opens/reads/closes each jar, and my jdk-linked application appears to open/read (but not close) each jar.  I'm not sure why that behavior is different.  Here's the filtered output from truss which shows the jars being opened by my application:

```
2847:19468/1:   open("/system/pkg/jdk/1.7.0_72/src/x86_64-pc-solaris2.10/jdk1.7.0_72/jre/lib/rt.jar", O_RDONLY) = 10
4804:19468/1:   open("/opt/mqm/java/lib/com.ibm.mqjms.jar", O_RDONLY) = 16
4871:19468/1:   open("/opt/mqm/java/lib/jms.jar", O_RDONLY) = 17
4888:19468/1:   open("/opt/mqm/java/lib/com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar", O_RDONLY) = 18
4907:19468/1:   open("/opt/mqm/java/lib/jta.jar", O_RDONLY) = 19
4924:19468/1:   open("/opt/mqm/java/lib/com.ibm.mq.headers.jar", O_RDONLY) = 20
4941:19468/1:   open("/opt/mqm/java/lib/com.ibm.mq.jar", O_RDONLY) = 21
4958:19468/1:   open("/opt/mqm/java/lib/com.ibm.mq.pcf.jar", O_RDONLY) = 22
4976:19468/1:   open("/opt/mqm/java/lib/connector.jar", O_RDONLY) = 23
4993:19468/1:   open("/opt/mqm/java/lib/com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar", O_RDONLY) = 24
5008:19468/1:   open("/opt/mqm/java/lib/dhbcore.jar", O_RDONLY) = 25
5027:19468/1:   open("/opt/mqm/java/lib/rmm.jar", O_RDONLY) = 26
5047:19468/1:   open("/opt/mqm/java/lib/jndi.jar", O_RDONLY) = 27
5066:19468/1:   open("/opt/mqm/java/lib/ldap.jar", O_RDONLY) = 28
5081:19468/1:   open("/opt/mqm/java/lib/fscontext.jar", O_RDONLY) = 29
5098:19468/1:   open("/opt/mqm/java/lib/providerutil.jar", O_RDONLY) = 30
5117:19468/1:   open("/opt/mqm/java/lib/CL3Export.jar", O_RDONLY) = 31
11229:19468/93: open("/system/pkg/jdk/1.7.0_72/src/x86_64-pc-solaris2.10/jdk1.7.0_72/jre/lib/rt.jar", O_RDONLY) = 50
```

sample code which works:

```
public class SimpleWMQJMSPubSub {

  // System exit status value (assume unset value to be 1)
  private static int status = 1;

  /**
   * Main method
   *
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Variables
    MQTopicConnection connection = null;
    MQTopicSession session = null;
    MQTopic topic = null;
    MQTopicPublisher publisher = null;
    MQTopicSubscriber subscriber = null;

    try {
      // Create a connection factory
      MQTopicConnectionFactory cf = new MQTopicConnectionFactory();

      // Set the properties
      cf.setHostName("mq");
      cf.setPort(1414);
      cf.setTransportType(JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP);
      cf.setQueueManager("QMAPC");
      cf.setChannel("JAVA.CHANNEL");
```

my code which fails:

```
  public MQConnection(String newHostname, String newQueueManagerName,
              int newPort, String newChannelName,
              String newClientId, String newBrokerSubqueueName) {

    this.hostname = newHostname;
    this.queueManagerName = newQueueManagerName;
    this.port = newPort;
    this.channelName = newChannelName;
    this.clientId = newClientId;
    this.brokerSubqueueName = newBrokerSubqueueName;

    try {
      factory = new MQTopicConnectionFactory();

      factory.setTransportType(JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP);
      factory.setQueueManager(queueManagerName);
      factory.setHostName(hostname);
      factory.setChannel(channelName);
      factory.setClientId(clientId);
      factory.setPort(port);
```

Both blocks have code have (nearly) identical import clauses [not shown for brevity] (my program has a few additional ones since it invokes other APIs - but the mq imports are extremely similar).

Here is how the jvm is created in my application:  the max-heap is set to 256M, the min-heap is 64M.  I've tried using larger values as well, no difference.  AHIJAVA_OPTIONS_COUNT = 5

```
void jvmSession::initJvm() {
  if (!jvmExists) {
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    JavaVMOption options[AHIJAVA_OPTIONS_COUNT];
    JNIEnv *aThrowawayEnv;
    jint result;

    RWCString aClassPathOption = "-Djava.class.path=";
    aClassPathOption.append(theClasspath.data());

    RWCString aLibraryPathOption = "-Djava.library.path=";
    aLibraryPathOption.append(theJavaLibraryPath.data());

    RWCString disableJITOption = "-Djava.compiler=none";

    RWCString aMaxHeapOption = "-Xmx";
    aMaxHeapOption.append(theJavaMaxHeap.data());

    RWCString aMinHeapOption = "-Xms";
    aMinHeapOption.append(theJavaMinHeap.data());

    options[0].optionString = (char *)aClassPathOption.data();
    options[1].optionString = (char *)aLibraryPathOption.data();
    options[2].optionString = (char *)disableJITOption.data();
    options[3].optionString = (char *)aMaxHeapOption.data();
    options[4].optionString = (char *)aMinHeapOption.data();

    vm_args.version = 0x00010002;
    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.nOptions = AHIJAVA_OPTIONS_COUNT;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_TRUE;
    /* Create the Java VM */
    result = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&theJvm, (void**)&aThrowawayEnv, &vm_args);
```

the 'new MQTopicConnectionFactory()' throws a NullPointerException, and a FFST report is dumped to stderr which I can only post the incomplete parts due to StackOverflow post size limitations and "this looks like spam" false positives:

```
                                    FDCTitle


Product          :- ProductName
Date/Time        :- Fri Jul 12 19:31:42 EDT 2019
System time      :- 1562974302503
Operating System :- SunOS
UserID           :- rhb
Java Vendor      :- Oracle Corporation
Java Version     :- 24.72-b04

Source Class     :- com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.PINLSServices
Source Method    :- createException(String,HashMap)
ProbeID          :- XC003001
Thread           :- name=Thread-1 priority=5 group=main ccl=<ContextClassLoader is null>

                                      Data
                                      ----

Data        :- none
No Components Found

xxxxx

Stack trace to show the location of the FFST call
|   FFST Location  :-  java.lang.Exception
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.getCurrentPosition(Trace.java:2019)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.createFFSTString(Trace.java:1958)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.ffstInternal(Trace.java:1847)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.Trace.ffst(Trace.java:1660)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.PINLSServices.createException(PINLSServices.java:121)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:233)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsErrorUtils.createException(JmsErrorUtils.java:131)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsFactoryFactoryImpl.getInstance(JmsFactoryFactoryImpl.java:172)
|       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
|       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
|       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
|       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
|       at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(JmsFactoryFactory.java:182)
|       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.initialiseMQConnectionFactory(MQConnectionFactory.java:3296)
|       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.<init>(MQConnectionFactory.java:265)
|       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQTopicConnectionFactory.<init>(MQTopicConnectionFactory.java:78)
|       at com.nvs.ahi.mq.MQConnection.<init>(MQConnection.java:85)

xxxxx


|   connectionTypeName  :-  com.ibm.msg.client.wmq
|   exception           :-  ExceptionDepth is 3
|   exception           :-  
|   |   Cause:1       :-  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
|   |   Cause:2       :-  java.lang.NullPointerException
|   |   StackTrace:1  :-  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
|   |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
|   |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
|   |       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
|   |       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
|   |       at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(JmsFactoryFactory.java:182)
|   |       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.initialiseMQConnectionFactory(MQConnectionFactory.java:3296)
|   |       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.<init>(MQConnectionFactory.java:265)
|   |       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQTopicConnectionFactory.<init>(MQTopicConnectionFactory.java:78)
|   |       at com.nvs.ahi.mq.MQConnection.<init>(MQConnection.java:85)
|   |       at com.nvs.ahi.mq.OutgoingConnection.<init>(OutgoingConnection.java:45)
|   |       at com.nvs.ahi.siview.AHISiViewAdapter.initMQ(AHISiViewAdapter.java:212)
|   |       at com.nvs.ahi.siview.AHISiViewAdapter.startIncoming(AHISiViewAdapter.java:474)
|   |       at com.nvs.ahi.jnibridge.AHIremote.startIncoming(AHIremote.java:105)
|   |   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
|   |       at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsFactoryFactoryImpl.getInstance(JmsFactoryFactoryImpl.java:174)
|   |       ... 13 more
|   |   
|   |   StackTrace:2  :-  java.lang.NullPointerException
|   |       at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsFactoryFactoryImpl.getInstance(JmsFactoryFactoryImpl.java:174)
|   |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
|   |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
|   |       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
|   |       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
|   |       at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(JmsFactoryFactory.java:182)
|   |       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.initialiseMQConnectionFactory(MQConnectionFactory.java:3296)
|   |       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.<init>(MQConnectionFactory.java:265)
|   |       at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQTopicConnectionFactory.<init>(MQTopicConnectionFactory.java:78)
|   |       at com.nvs.ahi.mq.MQConnection.<init>(MQConnection.java:85)
|   |       at com.nvs.ahi.mq.OutgoingConnection.<init>(OutgoingConnection.java:45)
|   |       at com.nvs.ahi.siview.AHISiViewAdapter.initMQ(AHISiViewAdapter.java:212)
|   |       at com.nvs.ahi.siview.AHISiViewAdapter.startIncoming(AHISiViewAdapter.java:474)
|   |       at com.nvs.ahi.jnibridge.AHIremote.startIncoming(AHIremote.java:105)
|   |   
No Components Found
```

Comment: First comment is that 7.5 has been out of support from IBM since April 30 2018.  MQ v8.0 goes out of support April 30 2020.  I would recommend you go with MQ v9.1.0.2, this is backward compatible with older MQ queue managers.

Comment: I'm aware that mq/7.5 is on extended support since April/2018; due to circumstances beyond my control in this environment, this is the hand I'm dealt with.  Notice I'm coming from mq/6, which is even more ancient!

Comment: As I mentioned higher version of MQ jar files can communicate with older version of MQ servers, and as an added benefit for MQ v8.0 and later there is now a officially relocatable jar file as well as a java only package.  You would just need to download the Java-All client from one of the download pages you can find via google search for `MQC8`, `MQC9, or `MQC91`.  In this file you would only need the `com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar` and `jms.jar`.  In addition if you utilize a "binding" file you would need the `fscontext.jar` and `providerutil.jar`.

Comment: I would suggest you try to capture a IBM MQ JMS trace, you can do this using the following command line java system properties `-Dcom.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.outputName=/path/to/mqjms.trc -Dcom.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.status=ON`  You can also do this programatically with `System.setProperty("com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.outputName","/path/to/mqjms.trc");` and `System.setProperty("com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.status","ON");`.

Comment: Have you tried running the Java application outside of your C++ framework?  Also, are you connecting in bindings or client mode?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible to run the application outside of the c++ framework; it's in the framework because there are jni bindings to c++ calls.

Comment: I have confirmed the same behavior occurs when using the 9.1.0.2 mq client jar distribution as well.  It seems like something was changed between version 6 and version 7.5 which works in a regular java jvm but not for my linked-in jvm.

Comment: The tracing never creates the file I specified - verified as much with 'truss' on the binary.   What's especially curious is that there are other invocations of reflection going on in the program which succeed, so why the mq reflection would be failing is unexplainable (by me)

Comment: When you tried with 9.1.0.2 did you use just the allclient.jar and jms.jar?

Comment: Yes, just those 2 jars; same failure again in the FFST

Comment: Have you tried the trace with 9.1.0.2 or only the older 7.5.  I know those trace options work with 9.1, not sure if they were different at 7.5

Comment: Also note that if you want to have Stackoverflow alert someone that you are responding to them you need to use the @ syntax, like @JoshMc.  You being the poster of this question will always get alerted so no need for me to  @ Rick you.

Comment: @JoshMc It looks like the tracing doesn't start showing anything until something more interesting than a new object is created, whether for 7.5 or 9.1.  The trace file is never even created.

Comment: Is that the same when you try a trace with the IBM sample?  As far a I know it should start tracing on the first MQ call, `new MQTopicConnectionFactory` for example.

Comment: @JoshMC - Very interesting: my c++ application has the JNIEnv::FindClass() methods (which ultimately call my code which calls mq APIs) running in a thread besides thread-1.  The AttachCurrentThread() calls are made appropriately beforehand.  However, if I make a call into the jvm to a static method which does nothing more than a 'new MQTopicConnectionFactory()' and returns while I'm on thread-1, BEFORE I invoke the rest of my normal java code on a different thread, everything works properly!  (And the trace files finally show up).  I will try to isolate the problem further

Comment: @Rick, could you expand on why you have c++ calling out to the IBM MQ Java code vs just directly using the IBM MQ C libraries or even the IBM MQ C++ libraries (Noted in recent question these C++ libs were stabilized so do not support some newer features such as pub/sub).

Comment: @JoshMc - It's a long story, but it's a piece of legacy code which had business and technical requirements which drove using java mq along with c++ APIs.  (Other applications in our suite either use ibm mq java in pure java, and other 100% c++ ones use ibm mqm c/c++ libraries.  This one gets to be extra special)

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I know that as noted c++ libs don't support PUB/SUB, but the C libraries would support all the JMS has to offer currently. In the past prior to MQ v7.0 Pub/Sub was only a JMS feature, as of 7.0 and later Pub/Sub is available for other APIs like C and .Net and XMS. XMS is a JMS like API IBM has released for .NET and for C++, so that is also another option as it should support all that JMS has. So maybe if you can't get this working you could leverage similar JMS code and just port it to XMS?  (*JMS only supports Shared Subscriptions and Delayed messages).

Comment: @JoshMc - other parts of our project are using mqm/6 C libraries, and the pub/sub mechanism works - I have a c++ library wrapper around it which uses it.  The XMS library ibm offered back at the time had too many bugs (having to do with race conditions in multi-threaded applications at startup) to rely upon, which is why I used the very reliable C libraries instead.  My understanding is the XMS libraries are better now.  This particular problematic component already has been retargeted to a native c++ application in our suite, but not yet deployed.  Key word here: legacy application!